# java rule for extends and implements

Tags: java

While coding I created a class that `extends ArrayList<>` and `implements Iterable<>`. The code is :

```
public class Testclass extends ArrayList<Object>, implements Iterable<Object> { }
```

Netbeans reported an error:

```
'{' expected
```

How to prevents this?

Comment: works in eclipse. I don't see why it would be a problem. can you clarify what the error is , it might help.

Comment: If you are extending ArrayList, I hope your class **'is a'** collection, i.e. it's very nature is a group of elements. Otherwise, use delegation, i.e. have an internal `ArrayList`.

Comment: Did you *read* the error? Didn't it *just* say that you need to implement the methods definied by Iterator?

Comment: code is this
`public class Testclass extends ArrayList<Object>, implements Iterable<Object> {

}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments:

> error is '{' expected
>
> code is this `public class Testclass extends ArrayList<Object>, implements Iterable<Object> { }`

Remove that comma `,`. It doesn't belong there. It's just a syntax error.

In the future, please **read** the error message. If you can't interpret it, even not after a little Googling, just ask it here, complete with the entire error message and the code which caused it. This way you will get better suited answers sooner than guessing randomly for the cause ;)

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList does not implement Iterator. Maybe you mean Iterable?

Anyway, it is not a problem to implement an interface that a superclass already implements (it is just redundant).

What error are you getting? It seems to be about something else. If you are using generics, did you make sure the types match on superclass and interface?

Also, it seems to be against the spirit of the Collection and Iterator interfaces to have an object that is both at the same time. At the very least, it is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

For a class that extends ArrayList and implements Iterator, you need three methods:

```
public boolean hasNext()
public Object next()
public void remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the coma between   and implements

I do not know what you are doing but you do not want a class that extends ArrayList and implements iterator.

Just implement List (or even Collection if you can). If someone wants the iterator they can just call the method yourList.iterator(). You can even return your custom iterator if that is what you really want.